# Sparse recovery with L1 shrinkage iteration for higher denominational image classification

Tags: least-squares, regularization, sparse-matrices, sparsity

For 2 months I have been studying sparse recovery and its applications for image classification and I have found that it's a broad area in mathematics which gives rise to a wide variety of regularization techniques. However, I am struggling to understand and implement the sparse recovery of the sparse vector by $L_1$ shrinkage iteration based on prior knowledge of labels.

Actually, I have a dictionary size $200 \times 58000$ (fat matrix) which constructed by a prior knowledge of classes (which needs to be redundant), and I have the knowledge of labels and I try to find the $L^1$ optimal solution using soft-shrinkage iteration which is as follows:

We have the linear combination.
$$y = Dx$$
and we use the least squares method to minimize $x$

$$\|y - Dx\|^2 + \lambda\|x\|_1\to\min_x$$

My question is, how to compute the $x$ first and then create an iterative method to update its quantity?

Or should I initialize $x$ to e.g $0$ and then wrap it with an iterative method to be updated? if so, how to formulate that particular iterative method?

Appreciate your help and response.

## Edited

Is the following equation the derivation of least squire with $L_1$?
How can I end up to the following equation?

Note: Of course the superscripts denote the number of iterations.

$$x^{n+1} = S\lambda\ /2(x^n + D^T(y - D x^n)) $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may solve the minimisation problem

$$\|y-Dx\|+\lambda\|x\|_1\to\min_x$$

using the so-called Fast Iterative Shrinkage Thresholding Algorithm (FISTA).

It's an iterative method which essentially consists of setting of setting the step size $L$ as the largest eigenvalue of $D^\ast D$, the initial values as $z_1=x_0$, $t_1=1$ and iterating

$$z_k=\operatorname{prox}_{L\frac{1}{\lambda}\|\cdot\|_1}(y-D^\ast(y-Dx_k)),$$
$$t_{k+1}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4t^2_k}}{2},$$
$$x_{k+1}=z_k+\left(\frac{t_k-1}{t_{k-1}}\right)(z_k-z_{k-1}).$$

Note that the nice property of the $\|\cdot\|_1$ regularisation term is that it has a closed form proximal mapping operator:

$$\operatorname{prox}_{\alpha\|\cdot\|_1}(x)=\operatorname{sign}(x_i)\max\{|x_i|-\alpha,0\},$$
which is just the soft thresholding operator.

You can read more about FISTA here: [FISTA](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiU4Pays97eAhWObFAKHbVjCoYQFjAAegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpeople.rennes.inria.fr%2FCedric.Herzet%2FCedric.Herzet%2FSparse_Seminar%2FEntrees%2F2012%2F11%2F12_A_Fast_Iterative_Shrinkage-Thresholding_Algorithmfor_Linear_Inverse_Problems_(A._Beck%2C_M._Teboulle)_files%2FBreck_2009.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1lKgA_n97ZG__4EKmwNuWp)

Comment: Dear Kemal, I do appreciate you for the answer. I have found it helpful. BTW,
I have added an Edited part which tells the point which I want.